# Can't set signal from within async piped Observable

Tags: observable, async-pipe, angular16, angular-signals

When I try setting a `signal` value from within an `Observable` that gets piped to `async`, I get the error:

> Error: NG0600: Writing to signals is not allowed in a `computed` or an
> `effect` by default. Use `allowSignalWrites` in the
> `CreateEffectOptions` to enable this inside effects.

But I'm not inside a `computed` or an `effect`, I'm inside an `Observable`. I also only get this through the `async` pipe; if I subscribe to the `Observable` and set my `data` in the `next` handler, it works as expected. Is this by design, or is it a bug?

```js
refreshTrigger = new BehaviorSubject<void>(undefined);
refreshing = signal(false);
data = this.refreshTrigger.pipe(
  tap(() => {
    console.log("Refreshing");
    this.refreshing.set(true);
  }),
  map(() => "Doing real work here"),
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

```html
{{refreshing() ? "Refreshing" : "Not refreshing"}} {{data | async}}
```

Comment: I didn't see any signal code in the linked stackblitz?

Comment: It seems unnecessary to have a `BehaviorSubject` and a `signal` and react to one to set the other. You should be able to react directly to the signal value. So whatever code is setting `refreshTrigger.next(x)` could just do `refreshing.set(x)`.

Comment: @DeborahK: I would think that the names of the objects would make it perfectly clear that the signal is a side effect of the real action. But I'll take a look at the stackblitz, I definitely had code in it.

Comment: Okay, I have no idea what happened to the stackblitz. I guess I'll just go ahead and remove it since I seem to have received an answer without it.

Comment: Oops, I thought I had the return from a different rxjs function than the tap, let me fix that.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

```
 The bug has been fixed in the Angular 16.1.0-next.3.
```

It works fine when you make the observable asynchronous, as mentioned by [@matthieu-riegler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/884123/matthieu-riegler) on [GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/50382).

You can workaround this issue by adding rxjs `delay` operator

```
data = this.refreshTrigger.pipe(
    delay(1),
    tap(() => {
      console.log('Refreshing');
      this.refreshing.set(true);
      return 'hello';
    }),
    shareReplay(1)
);
```

Comment: Sounds promising, I'll try it after the weekend.

Comment: I got pulled to another project before I could try this, and it looks like it will be a while before I can return, but I just wanted to update that the GitHub issue you created has been marked as Completed, so it should theoretically be fixed once the next release is ready, which isn't something I've had a need to wait for with Angular before, so I don't know what kind of timeframe that might be.

Comment: Also, run-on sentences FTW.